# Is it possible to use document.writeln ( using Javascript) when trying to create a nested list?

Tags: javascript, list, nested

Is it possible to use document.writeln when trying to create a nested list?
I am at the very very basic of learning javascript and don't know what I am doing wrong. I need to create a nested list using document.writeln, which seems to work. But, when I try to get it verified, a get a bunch of errors and it doesn't seem to be valid. Is it even possible to do what I am doing. For example. I have in the head (in the script area) something like:

```
var number1 = {"Name": "Smith", "First Name": "John", "Number": "58"};
```

and in the script area in the body I have:

```
document.writeln("<ul>");
document.writeln("<li>" + "Individual : ");
document.writeln("<ul>");
for (x in number 1) {
     document.writeln("<li>" + number1[x] + "</li>");}
}
document.writeln("</li></ul></ul>");
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to validate?

Comment: I'm tempted to flag as a duplicate now that there's the other, but I don't know that this is *really* a duplicate, since the re-post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641791/problems-with-validating-a-document-when-trying-to-create-a-nested-list-using-jav - doesn't really say that document.write is required, so someone could answer with the 'right' way to do it (w/o document.write) and have it accepted, but not to this one. @Kim, to make it easy, you may just want to close this question, since your other is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this line is wrong:

```
document.writeln("</li></ul></ul>");
```

That should be:

```
document.writeln("</ul></li></ul>");
```

EDIT: You've also got an extra closing brace:

```
for (x in number 1) {
   document.writeln("<li>" + number1[x] + "</li>");} // Remove the extra } here
}
```

So the test content I'm using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="asdf" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var number1 = {"Name": "Smith", "First Name": "John", "Number": "58"};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>asdf</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write("<ul>");
document.write("<li>" + "Individual : ");
document.write("<ul>");
for (x in number1) {
     document.write("<li>" + number1[x] + "<\/li>");
}
document.write("<\/ul><\/li><\/ul>");
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example now validates and works.

Comment: and ty this helps, I'm down to 4 errors now.  Still trying to figure out the rest though.  Man I feel like such a noob lol XD

Comment: As jforberg suggested in his comment, posting the errors you're getting would help resolve the others.

Comment: Line 58, Column 28: document type does not allow element "ul" here
        document.write("<ul>");Line 58, Column 29: character data is not allowed here
        document.write("<ul>");Line 60, Column 29: character data is not allowed here
        document.write("<ul>"); Line 62, Column 53: character data is not allowed here
        {document.write("<li>" + number1[x] + "</li>");}

Comment: Based on that, I think we need further context. What content/html is above this?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: :) Sorry, a bit more than that. `document type does not allow element "ul" here` suggests that the ul is getting inserted into the document where it isn't allowed, such as within a paragraph element. Perhaps 3 or 4 lines above?

Comment: no actually.  its after an <h2>header</h2>and only after, not in.  I only put it in the body, and not in a paragraph.

Comment: Found another error which I've noted above. I also dropped in a test document I created, based upon your comments here, and the errors I'm getting in Firebug are `End tag for element ... which is not open` errors. What validator are you using?

Comment: Well, I've updated my test document with code that validates (had to escape the closing slash). However, looking again at your comment above you have `document.write("<ul>");` not `document.writeln("<ul>");`  Are you sure the code above is on lines 58-62? Is the page at a publicly available location that we can look at?

Comment: no actually its my own personal document.  I'm not posting everything from it cause its got some personal information on it.  Also I changed the lns to just write.

Comment: Well, if you're only getting those errors, based on what you've provided above, I'm stumped. You could try changing the `("</`s to `("<\/` but I'm extremely doubtful that will resolve this particular error. #64 on http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html covers this, and suggests you may want to verify that the elements in your head are appropriate for the doctype you've selected. "Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects." One way to test is to pull out that entire script element and verify the rest of the document validates.

Comment: I already know it does validate without this section.  Ty anyways, I know its hard to see whats going on without me giving all the information.  I'll try the <\/ thing.  If it doesn't work, I got some people I can ask on MOnday.  And by the way this is my doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: I'm going to post this again, and post the whole thing and point out what I got wrong in another question.  ty for the help though!  =)

Comment: The doctype helps. See http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/document-alert-confirm/writing-text.php So basically put `//<![CDATA[` on the line before your js (right after `<script>`, and then `\\]]>` after, right before `</script>`.

Comment: Updated in my example above, and also added as an answer to your second post. FYI, generally it's a better idea to edit your question on Stack Overflow with the expanded details, instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The space between number and 1 in `for (x in number 1)` makes this invalid JavaScript. Also, the order of closing elements is wrong;

```
document.writeln("</li></ul></ul>");
```

should be

```
document.writeln("</ul></li></ul>");
```

However, it is not a good idea to use `document.writeln` in general, especially when the input (`number1` in your case) can be influenced by the user. For example, take the following input:

```
var number1 = {"Name": "Smith<h1>"};
```

This input will result in the layout of your site being broken. In general, directly writing user input with `document.writeln` allows users of your website to deface it and hijack other user's cookies by exploiting the [Cross-site scripting vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Instead of using `document.write`, use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction) and/or [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works).

Comment: oh I made that up.  I actually am using different variables but I do know what you mean.  Think of it as number1 instead.

Comment: @Kim Ok. I added a long update that explains why using `document.writeln` is not a good idea in general (and a note to the wrong order of closing tags).