# Problems with validating a document when trying to create a nested list using javascript

Tags: javascript, list, nested

Here is my whole document.  I'm having problems with the part in the head that starts with var tabNom1

and in the body after "`Partie 2: Affichage du contenu HTML à partir de JavaScript" and before "Partie 3: Affichage et animation des images`"

I am getting these errors:

```
Line 58, Column 28: document type does not allow element "ul" here
        document.write("<ul>"); Line 58, Column 29: character data is not allowed here
        document.write("<ul>"); Line 60, Column 29: character data is not allowed here
        document.write("<ul>"); Line 62, Column 53: character data is not allowed here
        {document.write("<li>" + tabNom1[x] + "</li>");}
```

In this document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>


<meta content="fr-ca" http-equiv="Content-Language"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css"/>

<title>TP3</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
                function addNumbers()
                {
                        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Notetp1").value);
                        var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Notetp2").value);
                        var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Notetp3").value);
                        var val4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Noteexamenintra").value);
                        var val5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Noteexamenfinal").value);

                        var ansD = document.getElementById("Note finale");
                        ansD.value = val1 + val2 + val3 +val4 + val5;
                }


var tabNom1 = {"Nom": "Smith", "Prenom": "John", "CodePermanent": "SMIT23325202", "Login": "Smith" }; 
 </script>

<style type="text/css">

  body {font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}  
  h2 {font-weight:bold;}

 </style>

</head>

 <body>


<h2>Partie 1: Formulaire du calcul de la note</h2>


        Note tp1 : <input id="Notetp1" name="Note tp1" value="" type="text"/>
        Note tp2 : <input id="Notetp2" name="Note tp2" value="" type="text"/>
        Note tp3 : <input id="Notetp3" name="Note tp3" value="" type="text"/>
        Note examen intra : <input id="Noteexamenintra" name="Note examen intra" value=""   type="text"/>
        Note examen final : <input id="Noteexamenfinal" name="Note examen final" value="" type="text"/>
        <input name="Sumbit" value="Afficher la note finale" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()" type="button"/>
        Note final : <input id="Notefinal" name="Note final" value="" type="text"/>


<h2>Partie 2: Affichage du contenu HTML à partir de JavaScript</h2>


        <script type="text/javascript">


        document.write("<ul>");
        document.write("<li>" + "Equipier numéro 1:");
        document.write("<ul>");
        for (x in tabNom1) 
        {document.write("<li>" + tabNom1[x] + "</li>");}
        document.write("</ul></li></ul>");

</script>

<h2>Partie 3: Affichage et animation des images</h2>

</body></html>
```

Comment: oops added a comment i don't need =P

Comment: Actually, `document.write` should not work at all in XHTML documents: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write#Notes

Comment: does document.writeln work?  what should I use instead?

Comment: @luxun: Why the `homework` tag?

Comment: because it is homework XD  luxun added it and he's right btw

Comment: Follow the link, `document.writeln` is not supported either. You should properly append the element using DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Felix King: In his original question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641389/is-it-possible-to-use-document-writeln-using-javascript-when-trying-to-create - he does mention it's for an assignment.

Comment: Also, the Part I, Part II et cetera was a tip off :)

Answer (score 1):

As noted to the answer to the first iteration of this question, update your body script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<ul>");
    document.write("<li>" + "Equipier numéro 1:");
    document.write("<ul>");
    for (x in tabNom1) 
    {document.write("<li>" + tabNom1[x] + "<\/li>");}
    document.write("<\/ul><\/li><\/ul>");
//]]>
</script>
```

That's adding CDATA and escaping the `/` in your closing elements.

See http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/document-alert-confirm/writing-text.php for examples.

Comment: And of course, the best solution would be to use, for example, jQuery to handle this, but since he's looking for a document.write/document.writeln solution ...

Comment: jQuery is not the answer to everything. And `document.write` does actually not work in XHTML documents (if served properly).

Comment: oh my gosh it worked ty!!!!!!!!!!!!!  I'm going to check more on CDATA to see what that is exactly to try to understand more why it worked.  But seriously!  Yeah, I've been so stuck!  XD =D

Comment: ok ty for telling me.  I'm actually not sure why my prof is making us use it but yeah, i understand that know.

Comment: @Felix King It's not, but chances are in the real world you're going to already be using a library for the rest of your site. And I assume you mean serving as XML (which no one realistically does :D )? You're probably right. But with a test document this ran fine on Firefox 5, Chrome current, and IE 9. *Shrug*

Comment: @Kim, unless that's part of the requirement, you may want to change the doctype, per Felix King's comment regarding it possibly not working (with his rep score, I'm going to assume he's right).

Comment: @James: I was referring to the MDC documentation, where it says *"Note: `document.write` (like `document.writeln`) does not work in XHTML documents (you'll get a "Operation is not supported" (`NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR`) error on the error console). This is the case if opening a local file with a `.xhtml` file extension or for any document served with an `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type. More information is available in the [W3C XHTML FAQ](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite)."* So it might work if it is served as HTML. Maybe browsers are also more relaxed regarding this...

Comment: @Felix: We're on the same page - the application/xhtml+xml MIME type is what I was referring to. The last time I read into it, most people were still just using text/html, and then people started claiming one or the other was harmful ... and then HTML5 hit the scene and things seemed to have gotten quieter about that. *Whew* :D

Comment: @James: Ok... I just wanted to point that out (in case OP gets in troubles later because of this). Using HTML5 is probably much better anyway ;)

Comment: @Felix: I'm the one that up-voted your comment on his question above :) I'll up-vote the one above in this thread as well (since you're right).

Comment: You already got +1 from me for the answer anyway ;) Although there might be better solutions for the overall problem, using `//<![CDATA[` for JavaScript in XHTML is necessary most of the time.

Comment: You know, technically he never says in this question that document.write is necessary. You could answer how to do this in pages served as XHTML ...

Comment: ty for the help.  I'm going to ask why we need to use document.write if it doesn't work with xhtml.  I heard that others were having issues with this assignment as well.  Perhaps I'm not the only one who got confused.